# syntax error at or near create when creating a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am creating a function in PostgreSQL for the first time and I am having a problem with the syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uni() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    mviews RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR mviews IN SELECT id,universite_adi FROM proaca.a LOOP

    INSERT INTO proaca.universite (id,ad,ulke_id) 
    VALUES (mviews.id,mviews.universite_adi,1)

    END LOOP;

    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"
Line 2: $BODY$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uni() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` to terminate the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Not sure if the syntax is the same, but in Oracle, you would ommit the `()` after `uni`

Comment: @ammoQ the `()` is required in Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error was solved by **a_horse** in the comments:

> *missing a `;` to terminate the `INSERT` statement*.

You don't need that loop. Just plain sql

```
create or replace function uni()
returns integer as $$

    insert into proaca.universite (id, ad, ulke_id) 
    select id, universite_adi, 1
    from proaca.a
    returning 1
    ;
$$ language sql;
```